# Indy SMTPServer send error message in OnConnect event

Tags: delphi, email, smtp, indy

I'd like to send an error message in my `SMTPServer.OnConnect` event (and of course go straight to the `OnDisconnect` event) to the client that I want to look like gmail temporarily blocked ip message: *421, "4.7.0", Our system has detected an unusual rate of unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily blocked. Review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.* This is how I tried to do it :

```
procedure TMainForm.SMTPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  errMess : String;
begin
  if ipTemporaryBanned(AContext.Binding.PeerIP) then begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('421  ' + 'IP temporary banned.');
    raise Exception.Create('IP temporary banned.');
  end;
end;
```

If I use `TIdSMTP` component there is no problem - I catch the error in my `try .. except` block, but when I use another mail client - like `Mozilla Thunderbird` - I cannot receive the error message that's being sent - it only says 'The connection with the SMTP server timed out.'
How can I send the error so that all mail clients can read it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no control over how clients handle errors from the server. It is the client's responsibility to **detect** errors from the server and act accordingly, but they are not obligated to **report** the server's error messages to the user, they are free to do whatever they want. There is nothing you can do about that on the server side. All you can do is send out your error message, and hope the clients at least have a logging capability so the user can hunt down the error message if needed.

That being said, I do suggest that you include an extended reply code in your error message (just like GMail does) so clients that recognize extended codes will at least know the error is temporary and security-related:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('421 4.7.0 IP temporary banned.');
```

Comment: And should I use ``raise Exception.Create('IP temporary banned.');`` or ``Exit;`` or something else server-side ?

Comment: After sending your custom greeting, you can either `raise` an exception or simply call `AContext.Connection.Disconnect` and exit. An uncaught exception will stop the client's worker thread, disconnecting the socket during its termination. If no exception is raised, the server will check if the socket is still connected after `OnConnect` exits before sending its default `Greeting`, and then the thread will stop when it sees the socket is no longer connected.  The end result will be the same either way - the socket is disconnected and the thread is stopped.

Comment: Technically, there is another option for handling your banning - you can derive a new component from `TIdSMTPServer` and override its virtual `SendGreeting()` method instead of using the `OnConnect` event. But you would still have to either `raise` an exception or call `Disconnect` to close the socket and stop the thread.